# Eliminating Manual Steps in AWS Amplify Deployment via Terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I am currently using AWS Amplify service for static hosting and facing an issue with the deployment process. I am attempting to deploy my React.js app to AWS Amplify using a Terraform script.

The Terraform script successfully launches the Amplify app on AWS, but I have to manually click the "Run build" button in the AWS Amplify app dashboard for the deployment to proceed. I would like to automate this process, so the deployment happens directly when the script runs, without the need for manual intervention.

How can I modify my Terraform script or any related configurations to automate the deployment process and eliminate the need to manually click the "Run build" button on the AWS Amplify app dashboard?

```
# Create an IAM role for Amplify builds
resource "aws_iam_role" "amplify_build_role" {
  name = "amplify-build-role"
  assume_role_policy = jsonencode({
    Version = "2012-10-17",
    Statement = [
      {
        Action = "sts:AssumeRole",
        Effect = "Allow",
        Principal = {
          Service = "amplify.amazonaws.com"
        }
      }
    ]
  })
}

# Policy

resource "aws_iam_policy" "policy" {
  name        = "amplify_policy"
  path        = "/"
  description = "My test policy"

  policy = jsonencode({
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "PushLogs",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "logs:CreateLogStream",
                "logs:PutLogEvents"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        },
        {
            "Sid": "CreateLogGroup",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "logs:CreateLogGroup",
            "Resource": "*"
        },
        {
            "Sid": "DescribeLogGroups",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "logs:DescribeLogGroups",
            "Resource": "*"
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Resource": [
                "*"
            ],
            "Action": [
                "codecommit:GitPull"
            ]
        }
    ]
  })
}


# Create an AWS Amplify app
resource "aws_amplify_app" "my_amplify_app" {
  name                    = var.app_name_amplify
  repository              = "https://git-codecommit.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/v1/repos/demo-react-app"
  enable_auto_branch_creation = true
  iam_service_role_arn     = aws_iam_role.amplify_build_role.arn
  build_spec = <<-EOT
    version: 1.0
    frontend:
      phases:
        preBuild:
          commands:
            - npm install
        build:
          commands:
            - npm run build
      artifacts:
        baseDirectory: build
        files:
          - '**/*'
      cache:
        paths:
          - node_modules/**/*
  EOT 
  auto_branch_creation_config {
    # Enable auto build for the created branch.
    enable_auto_build = true
  }
}

# Attach necessary permissions to the IAM role for Amplify builds
resource "aws_iam_policy_attachment" "amplify_build_policy_attachment" {
  name       = "amplify-build-policy-attachment"
  policy_arn = aws_iam_policy.policy.arn
  roles      = [aws_iam_role.amplify_build_role.name]
}

# Create an Amplify branch for automatic deployments
resource "aws_amplify_branch" "master" {
  app_id      = aws_amplify_app.my_amplify_app.id
  branch_name = "master"
}
```

I have tried many approaches, including following the Terraform official documentation, but I have not found any properties to automate this process. Can anyone provide assistance or guidance?